# KeyBoard Hangs While Typing

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

First Of All Happy New Year to all of you.

I am working on Chat Application My problem is that when i send a message to another user if i type another message while previous is going to other my keypad hangs for some time.When First message get delivered then keyboard comes in normal state from hanged state and the character i have typed get appeared.

Can anyone suggest me what to do to prevent keyboard from hang.Any Suggestion would be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hang? Keyboard rarely hangs. Show us some codes. Any error message?

Comment: You arent doing `work` on the UI Thread.... are you.... ^.^

Comment: use NSThreads in your application

Comment: For which i have to use NSThread For sending message or for tying Please suggest because where as i know We shouldn't work on typing with another thread.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor-there is no error message Only web service is hitting and making keyboard to hanf

Comment: @AshutoshMishra : See my answer and edit section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSThread](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as you want a unit of computational work done without necessarily either waiting for other units to finish, or holding up other computational work.

You can put almost any work into a thread, if it is sensible to do so.

A good example is a network request, where you set up a thread to download data from, say, a web server. Your thread will fire a "handler" function when it has completed its work. The handler works with the downloaded data; for example, parsing XML data from a web service.

You would use a thread in this example, because you don't want the entire application to lock up while your app downloads data over the network and processes it. An NSThread instance puts this unit of work into its own little "space" that allows the larger app to continue to interact with the user.

An example of where you do not want to use threads on the iOS platform is with UI updates (e.g., changing the state of any of the UIControl widgets). All UI updates happen on the main thread. If you use your own threads with UI widgets, the behavior is unpredictable and, more often than not, will simply not work.

EDIT :
For sending message you should use `NSThread`

Comment: You should avoid using threads explicitly if possible.  Read [“The Move Away from Threads” in Apple's *Concurrency Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW8).

Comment: Really  good answer Prateek Can you give me any link where can i find the example of NSThread Because I am using web service which uses JSON Value other than XML

Comment: @robmayoff-Then what would be helpful in this case? Do you have any suggestion

Comment: @AshutoshMishra : http://www.xprogress.com/post-36-threading-tutorial-using-nsthread-in-iphone-sdk-objective-c/

Comment: @Prateek- But if i am  Using NSThread I have to supervise when it is getting finished.Isn't it?

Comment: @robmayoff : I use this in my application, and my application is live with 1000 rating on app store, I prefer using NSThreads as he is going to send only one request using NSThreads which will not create any issue

Comment: @Prateek-Thanks for your suggestion I am going to do this in my app If i would found any problem i would post here

Answer (score 4):

You need to either use non-blocking, asynchronous functions/methods to send the message, or you need to send the message on a dispatch queue or an operation queue.

Both of these queue types are discussed in Apple's [*Concurrency Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1).

You can also watch some Apple developer videos about concurrency:

- [WWDC 2011 Session 308 - Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch in Practice](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=308)
- [WWDC 2011 Session 210 - Mastering Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=210)
- [WWDC 2012 Session 712 - Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712)
- [WWDC 2012 Session 211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211)
- [WWDC 2012 Session 235 - iOS App Performance: Responsiveness](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=235)

Comment: Can you suggest me any link which follows this thing and it will also suitable for me to understand rather than Doc

Comment: Read the Concurrency Programming Guide.  Watch the videos.

Comment: I will Read this and post if i found any difficulties in that By the way thanks for your link-